# cobbler sync - generating dhcpd.template file

Tags: cobbler

I am trying to resolve a cobbler issue, request your help/guidance on the same. we have spacewalk with cobbler. when I add a new host and do a cobbler sync, i am getting the below error and TASK FAILED.

```
rendering DHCP files
generating /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
Exception occured: <class 'cexceptions.CX'>
Exception value: 'Error templating file, check cobbler.log for more details'
```

when I cross check the cobbler.log, these entries were recorded...

```
Mon Apr 25 14:44:45 2016 - WARNING | errors were encountered rendering the       template
Mon Apr 25 14:44:45 2016 - WARNING |
[{'code': u'VFFSL(SL,"net0",True)/mac',
'exc_val': NotFound("cannot find 'net0'",),
'lineCol': (2, 11),
'rawCode': u'${net0/mac}',
'time': 'Mon Apr 25 14:44:45 2016'}]
```

Thanks
Nandakumar

Answer (score 0):

we found its was a profile with the system Profile with a wrong name, which was stopping creating the dhcpd.conf file. After removing the particular system profile, everything works well.

Thanks
Nandakumar